render Inline text from ashx file
I have an ashx file which returns plain text as below:
`<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="title" content="" />
<meta name="site" content="" />`

The question is how can I call this .ashx file to chuck the above text inline on the page? I have tried below
<link type="text/plain" href="/MetaTags.ashx">
Is it even possible? Any help is much appreciated.
